# How to set a Python variable to 'undefined'?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

In Python 3,  I have a global variable which starts as "undefined".

I then set it to something.

Is there a way to return that variable to a state of "undefined"?

@martijnpieters

EDIT - this shows how a global variable starts in a state of undefined.

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> global x
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve by undefining this variable? Do you just want to tidy up the namespace? Do you want to free up resources? Are you under the impression you need to undefine the variable before assigning something else to it?

Comment: How do you "have" a global variable before you define it in Python?

Comment: Python has no concept of 'undefined' like JavaScript has. A name exists, or it doesn't. If the name exists, it is defined, although you can bind it to the `None` singleton.

Comment: Hey why the downvotes? It's a perfectly reasonable question clearly asked and in fact, well answered. It's a global variable that starts in an undefined state. I don't want to set it to None because the function it is in will be re-entered multiple times. I just want to test if it is undefined and if it is undefined then initialise it. Sven's answer is spot on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters global variables start out undefined. See comment below None is not the same as undefined.

Comment: @neftas global variables start in a state of undefined.

Comment: @DukeDougal: *No they don't*. Global names start out bound to something. They don't exist otherwise.

Comment: @DukeDougal: see the [reference documentation on naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding): *Names refer to objects. Names are introduced by name binding operations.* and *When a name is not found at all, a `NameError` exception is raised. If the name refers to a local variable that has not been bound, a `UnboundLocalError` exception is raised.* So either a name is bound, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: @martijnpieters see the edit to the original post.

Comment: This argument is silly. One of you is saying it's undefined. The other is saying it doesn't exist. You're saying the same thing, aren't you? I think it's the "set it to" part of "set it to undefined" that gives the impression that one of you thinks undefined is an actual value.

Comment: @DukeDougal: You are confused about what the `global` keyword **does**. It does **not** define a name. It only tells the Python compiler that a name in a function should not be treated as a local, but should refer to a global name instead. It changes *scope*, it is not a definition. See the [`global` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement).

Comment: @martijnpieters OK I stand corrected. Doesn't justify a downvote though.

Comment: @DukeDougal: I didn't downvote, but I don't think your post is worthy of an upvote either. I instead chose to address your misunderstanding about terminology in comments.

Comment: @martijnpieters thanks I appreciate your answers I now better understand.  Sound likes I should be taking a different approach anyway to how I am implementing this bit of code rather than testing for undefined.

Comment: The OP is maybe trying to ask "How do you set a Python variable to null?" -- but because there's no null in Python (like some other languages have) the right answer below explains to use None.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can delete a global name `x` using

```
del x
```

Python doesn't have "variables" in the sense C or Java have.  In Python, a variable is just a tag you can apply to any object, as opposed to a name refencing some fixed memory location.

Deleting doesn't necessarily remove the object the name pointed to.

Comment: Note that if you stick this in a function, you'll just get an `UnboundLocalError` unless the function declares that it's referring to the global `x` with the line `global x`.

Answer (score 59):

You probably want to set it to None.

```
variable = None
```

Check if variable is "defined"

```
is_defined = variable is not None
```

You could delete the variable, but it is not really pythonic.

```
variable = 1
del variable
try:
    print(variable)
except (NameError, AttributeError):
    # AttributeError if you are using "del obj.variable" and "print(obj.variable)"
    print('variable does not exist')
```

Having to catch a NameError is not very conventional, so setting the variable to None is typically preferred.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to be able to test its 'undefined state', you should set it to None :

```
variable = None
```

and test with

```
if variable is None:
```

If you want to clean stuff, you can delete it, `del variable` but that should be task of the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks. I have exactly this problem, referencing something that was never set. It's set at the top of the function now.

Answer (score 3):

In light of the OP's comments:

```
# check if the variable is undefined
try:
    x
# if it is undefined, initialize it
except NameError:
    x = 1
```

And like the rest said, you can delete a defined variable using the `del` keyword.

Comment: This answer tests to see if the variable is in an undefined state.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a case when you actually want `undef`: function arguments that can have any value (including `None`), but we still need to know if the value was provided or not.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    """
    Some container class.
    """

    def pop(self, name, default):
        """
        Delete `name` from the container and return its value.

        :param name: A string containing the name associated with the
            value to delete and return.
        :param default: If `name` doesn't exist in the container, return
            `default`. If `default` is not given, a `KeyError` exception is
            raised.
        """
        try:
            return self._get_and_delete_value_for(name)
        except GetHasFailedError:
            if default is undefined:
                raise KeyError(name)
            else:
                return default
```

This is very much like `dict.pop`, and you need to know if `default` was given. One could fake that with `*args, **kwargs`, but that gets messy quickly, and having `undef` would really help.

IMO, the easiest approach for that is this:

```
_undef = object()


class Foo:
    """
    Some container class.
    """

    def pop(self, name, default=_undef):
        """
        Delete `name` from the container and return its value.

        :param name: A string containing the name associated with the
            value to delete and return.
        :param default: If `name` doesn't exist in the container, return
            `default`. If `default` is not given, a `KeyError` exception is
            raised.
        """
        try:
            return self._get_and_delete_value_for(name)
        except GetHasFailedError:
            if default is _undef:
                raise KeyError(name)
            else:
                return default
```

The leading underscore implies that the variable is private to the module and shouldn't be used outside of it, which suggests that `_undef` should not be used as an argument value, making it a good detector for "this value is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your var x as None

```
x = None
```

Comment: @justinengel (at)guillaume (at)damienfrancois None is not the same as undefined.

Comment: @DukeDougal We suggest using None instead, because the idea of an undefined variable is not "pythonic". Python programmers are very particular about how the language is used that's why PEP's were made. Pylint is what most python programmers use to check code syntax, and it will show an undefined variable as bad practice. http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/17/true-lies-and-falsy-values-in-python-and-javascript/

Comment: Isn't it still bad practice to be changing your mind about variables _at all_, in terms of pythonicness?

Answer (score -4):

Use this:

```
undefined = "undefined"
# del x isn't effective, so use "x = undefined"
x = undefined
```

Comment: Why is del not effective?

Comment: because ```del x``` will return an error, not undefined

Comment: Which is per my understanding exactly what was asked for.

Comment: using a string is bad idea. This string will be comparable with other strings, and for example, `x > "0"` is true after the code in the answer, same as `bool(x)` (code after `if x:` will execute)